# Help with this ragged array/substring program in C?

Tags: c, arrays, substring

so, I have a ragged array (called names) of length 200. each pointer in the array points to a string that is no longer than 50 characters and has no white spaces. I also have a string given through user-input called inname, with length 50, inname will be one of the strings stored in names. I need to find a way to go through the strings in my ragged array and find the string with the largest substring overlap with inname, excluding inname itself as that will be in the file. If no string has an overlap then we print out "no recommendation".
I've been melting trying to puzzle this out for many hours now, helps? O:) SO basically, the program finds the name in the array with the largest substring overlap with inname.
will edit to provide additional info if you need it

Comment: In a sense, It's not homework for uni though, so Its not like i'm turning this in for a grade or anything.

Comment: Can you change the name of your string array to something that doesn't imply that it contains a list of function pointers?

Comment: Still, generally good etiquette here to tag it as such, just so we know how we can help you best. What are you having trouble with? Looping over the array? Iterating through strings? Finding common substrings?

Comment: ah, my apologies then. I'm having trouble with the finding common substrings part

Comment: Does the problem call for overlaps in the middle of the string, or just starting from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't lead you to the most efficient way to find overlap (dynamic programming is one way--there are other crazy methods like suffix trees), but it should get you started:

First, think about how you would find the length of the overlap with the beginning of both strings aligned. For instance, find the longest overlap between these two:

```
programming
ungrammatical
```

In this case, only a single `m` overlaps--a length of 1.

Then think about how you would "shift" the strings and look for the overlap when they are aligned differently. (Don't actually change the strings: just change how you loop through them to compare them.) What is the overlap between these two?

```
programming
 ungrammatical
```

Think about how to look at all possible alignments. If you keep track of the longest one you find, you have the longest alignment between two particular strings.

After that, move on to checking all the different strings. Keep track of the one with the best match, and again, once you have looked at all of them, you have your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably start on the smaller problem of determining the size of the overlap between infunc and a single string.

Wikipedia goes over some algorithms for solving the [longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) (including pseudocode!)