# nul byte character in Rcpp function

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm looking for a way of comparing short strings for overlap.

I thought I might find a reasonable method using the `stringdist` package using the `lcs` method, but it appears to be doing something different.

The accepted answer to this C-tagged stackoverflow question:

[Detecting length of overlap between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026483/detecting-length-of-overlap-between-two-strings)

```
int overlap(const char *s1, const char *s2){
    int i = 0;
    while (*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0') {
        if (*s1++ == *s2++) i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

involves using nul byte character to represent empty strings.

How could I translate this into something that works in Rcpp? When I try wrapping it up in `cppFunction`, I get an error saying that this character is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you use `cppFunction` to define your C++ functions, you need to escape the `\`, i.e. if you want to have `\0` in the C++ code, you need to write `\\0` in the string you give to `cppFunction`:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction( "
int overlap(const char* s1, const char* s2){

  int i = 0;
  while (*s1 != '\\0' && *s2 != '\\0') {
    if (*s1++ == *s2++) i++;
  }
  return i;

}")
```

Which gives you:

```
> overlap( "foo", "foooo")
[1] 3
```

Note that you don't need that if you put your function in a .cpp file, which is what is recommended:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int overlap(const char* s1, const char* s2 ){

  int i = 0;
  while (*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0') {
    if (*s1++ == *s2++) i++;
  }
  return i;
}
```